# Float array to Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a float array representing a grayscale picture that I want to convert to an image in C#. How do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

        for (int j = 0; j < original.Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
            {
                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb((int)grayScale[i + j * original.Width], (int)grayScale[i + j * original.Width], (int)grayScale[i + j * original.Width]);

                newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
            }
        }

        Image img = (Image)newBitmap;
```

Comment: The OP has an array of floats. Your answer uses an array of bytes. I don't think it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft forum for converting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e57f7731-c703-4c17-b1a2-32b155f9b745)
[Example in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx)