# How I can convert float array to Bitmap or Uri to set it into image

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite

My ml model gives output an image. In android using tflite, I get output from the model as float array, now I want to convert this float array to Bitmap or URI to set it into the image.

My code:

predict.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // input image
        img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, 256, 256, true);


        try {
            Model model = Model.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 256, 256, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);


            TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
            tensorImage.load(img);

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();

            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            Model.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close();


            System.out.println(outputFeature0.getFloatArray().length);

            //imgView.setImageBitmap();
            //imgView.setImageURI();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle the exception
        }
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374130/float-array-to-image/5374318.

Comment: It is C# bro I need in Java, Thank you